# Convert code from es6 to es5? See example for the es6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, es6-class, es5-compatiblity

I have the following code in es6 and I want to convert it to es5.

```
class PowerArray extends Array {
  isEmpty() {
    return this.length === 0;
  }
}

let arr = new PowerArray(1, 2, 5, 10, 50);
console.log(arr.isEmpty()); // -> empty
console.log(arr.filter(item => item >= 10)); // -> 10, 50
```

I tried using Array.prototype.filter.call(context, callback), but I can't figure out what to pass in the first argument. Is it even possible to accomplish this?

I know I can use Babel, but this question is for learning purposes.

Comment: conversion from es6 to es5 is usually done using something like babel, not manually

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966830/why-inheriting-from-array-is-difficult-to-implement-in-es5

Comment: `arr.filter(function(item) { return item >= 10 })`  ?