# Proper subclassing of built-ins in ES5, counterproof to MDN statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm writing some in-depth educational materials about the object model, constructor functions and class mechanisms in Javascript. As I was reading sources I found this statement that I took the time to understand its reasons and ultimately, I found it not to be entirely true.

The MDN article on [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) sugests using [Reflect.construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) in order to subclass constructor functions (of course, it also advocates for the use of class syntax in ES6 code, but my interest now is on constructor functions).

As I see it, the requirements for proper subclassing are:

- the base constructor must action on the constructed object first, then the derived constructor
- the constructed object's prototype must be `Derived.prototype`, whose prototype must be `Base.prototype`
- the static properties should be inherited: `Derived`'s prototype should be `Base`.

There is also the implicit requirement that the base constructor's prechecks for `new` operator usage be satisfied. This is the key difference between constructor functions pre- and post-ES6:
in ES5, this precheck consisted of a `this instanceof Base` check (although [ECMAScript's 5.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_5.1_edition_june_2011.pdf) only describes the behaviours of built-ins with and without the new operator, while being ambiguous about how this check is performed).

The mdn article says:

> Note: In fact, due to the lack of `Reflect.construct()`, it is not possible to properly subclass built-ins (like `Error` subclassing) when transpiling to pre-ES6 code.

and gives this example of properly subclassing `Map` in ES6 code:

```js
function BetterMap(entries) {
  // Call the base class constructor, but setting `new.target` to the subclass,
  // so that the instance created has the correct prototype chain.
  return Reflect.construct(Map, [entries], BetterMap);
}

BetterMap.prototype.upsert = function (key, actions) {
  if (this.has(key)) {
    this.set(key, actions.update(this.get(key)));
  } else {
    this.set(key, actions.insert());
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(BetterMap.prototype, Map.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(BetterMap, Map);

const map = new BetterMap([["a", 1]]);
map.upsert("a", {
  update: (value) => value + 1,
  insert: () => 1,
});
console.log(map.get("a")); // 2
```

However, if `BetterMap` were defined instead as

```js
function BetterMap(entries) {
    var instance = new Map(entries);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, BetterMap.prototype);
    return instance;
}
```

wouldn't we achieve the same result, both in ES5 and ES6 (after also replacing the arrow functions in the example above with function expressions)? This satisfies all the above requirements and complies with any prechecks that `Map` might do, as it construct the object with `new`.

I tested the code above with my suggested changes on Node downgraded to 5.12.0 and it worked as expected.

Comment: It's not clear what you're suggesting. Without linking `BetterMap.prototype` to `Map.prototype`, it's not clear how you'll get access to the `Map` methods from the subclass instances.

Comment: I don't mean removing anything in the example given on MDN, only replacing the definition of BetterMap as presented. The linkings remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wouldn't we achieve the same result, both in ES5 and ES6?

No, since `Object.setPrototypeOf` is not available in ES5. This was really the main limitation, you [cannot subclass `Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261587/1048572) or `Function` in ES5 without relying on something like the non-standard (and now deprecated) `.__proto__` setter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967939/1048572) or [*How ECMAScript 5 still does not allow to subclass array*](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) for details.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense. I don't know how I didn't think about searching for Object.setPrototypeOf in the old spec before.